# How to add a header with timestamp to numpy_msg?

Tags: ros, rospy, message, message-filters

I am using the rospy with numpy [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/numpy) to create a publisher and subscriber that send numpy arrays to listener that uses an [ApproximateTimeSynchronizer](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters). However, I receive an error when I try to instantiate the listener:

```
[WARN] [1693265081.824595]: Cannot use message filters with non-stamped messages. Use the 'allow_headerless' constructor option to auto-assign ROS time to headerless messages.
```

So my understanding is that my message must contain a header with a time stamp. Is it possible to add a header with a timestamp to a `numpy_msg`? And if so, how do I this?

My message publisher construction:

```
from rospy_tutorials.msg import Floats
from rospy.numpy_msg import numpy_msg

l_lines_pub = rospy.Publisher('/l_lines_output', numpy_msg(Floats), queue_size=10)
r_lines_pub = rospy.Publisher('/r_lines_output', numpy_msg(Floats), queue_size=10)

l_lines_msg = np.asarray(ARRAY1)
r_lines_msg = np.asarray(ARRAY2)

l_lines_pub.publish(l_lines_msg)
r_lines_pub.publish(r_lines_msg)
```

And my subscriber looks like:

```
l_lines_sub = Subscriber('/l_lines_output', numpy_msg(Floats))
r_lines_sub = Subscriber('/r_lines_output', numpy_msg(Floats))

ats = ApproximateTimeSynchronizer([l_lines_sub, r_lines_sub], queue_size=5, slop=0.015)
ats.registerCallback(gotData)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to add a header with a timestamp to a `numpy_msg`

In short, yes, I think you just need to call `numpy_msg()` on a stamped message.

`numpy_msg()` isn't a message type, it's a conversion function that creates and returns a new type based on an existing ROS message type, see [here](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/noetic-devel/clients/rospy/src/rospy/numpy_msg.py#L83).

I have not used this myself, but it looks to me like it should work with any ROS message type that implements `serialize_numpy` and `deserialize_numpy` methods (see [here](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/noetic-devel/clients/rospy/src/rospy/numpy_msg.py#L87)). Furthermore, it appears that these two methods are auto-generated by the message generation system, and so I think you can call `numpy_msg()` on any ROS message, built-in or custom, including messages that include headers.

There's some more information here:

https://ros-users.narkive.com/2VzlEDxg/fast-methods-to-go-between-ros-pointcloud-and-numpy

As far as I can tell you should be able to simply replace your `rospy_tutorials/Floats` message with a suitable existing message or your own [custom message](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv#Using_msg) that includes a header and a floating point array type.

The use of generic numeric arrays to pass data is discouraged, as discussed here: [Stamped std_msgs](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/31038/stamped-std-msgs), so as far as I know there's no built-in stamped generic floating-point array. You could define one, but it'd be better to define a message where the array has a meaningful name.

Curiously, the Numpy serialization and deserialization code for many built-in messages doesn't actually use Numpy, I think because a philosophy of meaningful, well-named fields tends to favor single floating-point numbers with individual names.

I found [`sensor_msgs/LaserScan`](https://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/LaserScan.html) as one example of a stamped message that does contain array fields. Corresponding (old) autogenerated Python code for that message is [here](http://docs.ros.org/en/diamondback/api/sensor_msgs/html/__LaserScan_8py_source.html#l00213). This code uses `ndarray.tostring()` and `numpy.frombuffer()` for serialization and deserialization of the `ranges` and `intensities` fields.

A similar simpler message with a `Header` and a `float32[]` or `float64[]` array should work with `numpy_msg()` and give you the timestamp you need.

> listener that uses an `ApproximateTimeSynchronizer`. However, I receive an error when I try to instantiate the listener

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, maybe you don't need accurate timestamps from the publisher. Then I think you could also try:

```py
ats = ApproximateTimeSynchronizer(
      [l_lines_sub, r_lines_sub], 
      queue_size=5, slop=0.015, allow_headerless=True)
```

From [the `message_filters` wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters#ApproximateTime_Policy):

> If some messages are of a type that doesn't contain the header field, `ApproximateTimeSynchronizer` refuses by default adding such messages. However, its Python version can be constructed with `allow_headerless=True`, which uses current ROS time in place of any missing `header.stamp` field